# C++ `long long` variable type

Tags: c++, variable-types

I am now studying about writing binary files. I've seen this question on StackOverflow. And the author says, in his code

```
const unsigned long long size = 1ULL*1024ULL*1024ULL;
```

I don't actually know what are the `ULL symbols`. Could anybody give me some documentation about it? I have searched on Google, and everything I get is more documentation about writing files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a suffix that specifies the type of literal (in this case, integer literals).

You can find out more about this in the C++ standard, specifically in 2.14 - Literals

In your case, the answer lies in the following table (from this very part of the standard) :  `unsigned long long`.

[image: Integer literals suffixes]

Comment: BTW use the capital L instead of a lower case l as it is easy to confuse l with 1

Comment: Whomever authored "Table 6 -- Types of integer constants" would probably appreciate credit.

Comment: @JonathanMee I mention right above that it comes from the standard.

Answer (score 2):

It makes 1 and 1024 be `unsigned long long` constants or else they'd default to `int` (in terms of how many bytes the value will take to be represented):

`std::cout << sizeof(1ULL) << sizeof(1);`